# Magento 1.7 not login in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.7

I migrate an installation of magento 1.7 to my localhost, but when I want login in the admin panel, when I put the correct user and password, it reload the same page.

I probe with incorrect user and in the login show an error but if I use correct login show the same login but not redirect to my admin panel.

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using localhost in the url ?

Comment: Is a server ubuntu but local. the url is configure but is local. I use the correct because load the admin panel, the problem is in login

Comment: try to open it with Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Step 1: Clear your Browser cookie.

Step 2 : Login with correct login details.